# AES большой объем данных

Tags: java, криптография, aes

При расшифровке данных большого объема получаю исключение BadPaddingException: EVP_CipherFinal_ex

Функция расшифровки

```
    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted) {

    byte[] IV = //IV
    byte[] Key = //KEY

    try {

        SecretKeySpec SecretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Key, "AES");
        AlgorithmParameterSpec AlgorithmParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
        Cipher Cipher = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        Cipher.init(javax.crypto.Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, SecretKeySpec, AlgorithmParameterSpec);

        return Cipher.doFinal(bytesToBeDecrypted);

    } catch (InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

При расшифровке маленьких "строк", все работает отлично что примечательно.
В чем может быть проблема ?

Зашифровка AES происходит на сервере, на php

```
function Encrypt($dataToEncrypt)
{     
    $EncryptData = openssl_encrypt($dataToEncrypt, 'AES-256-CBC', $Key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $IV);

    return $EncryptData;
}
```

Comment: Без кода который шифрует не разобраться

Comment: А небольшие строки в 3 байта, например, корректно расшифровываются?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов да, все расшифровывается корректно!

Comment: Данные длиной 80 расшифровываются корректно, а длиной  222528 уже ошибка

Comment: Будет гораздо проще разобраться, если вы сделаете самодостаточный пример. Т.е. сгенерите ключ и IV, выложите php-скрипт, который этим ключом шифрует фиксированное сообщение, выложите java-класс, который пытается это же сообщение расшифровать. Прям вот чтобы можно было ваш код взять и сразу запустить.

Answer (score 0):

`BadPaddingException` может генерироваться если алгоритм выравнивания блоков при расшифровке не совпадает с алгоритмом выравнивания примененным при шифровании.

Алгоритмов выравнивания блоков (*padding*) вагон и маленькая тележка.

Краткий обзор [здесь](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography))

Самое правильное в этой ситуации посмотреть алгоритм паддинга примененный в шифровании, скорее всего это что-то типа *PKCS7Padding*

**Update**

Попробуйте шифровать так:

```
openssl_encrypt($dataToEncrypt, 'AES-256-CBC', $Key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $IV);
```

Comment: Но почему тогда при маленьком объеме данных он расшифровывает ?

Comment: У автора в коде, вроде, PKCS5Padding

Comment: У него в дешифровке `PKCS5Padding`, а в реальности при шифровании `openssl_encrypt()` согласно документации применяет `PKCS7Padding`

Comment: Не помогает исправление на PKCS7Padding

Comment: Как вариант дешифровка с `AES/CBC/NoPadding`...

Comment: AES/CBC/NoPadding тоже не помогает, пробовал с OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, на выходе вообще пустая строка если передать такой параметр.